# Sahi file and image upload error in playback

Tags: sahi

While trying to run script for image upload or file upload, I get following play back error in SAHI open source.

What could be done to prevent this error?

Script goes like:

```
_click(_link("プロフィール"));
_assertExists(_file("profile-fileupload"));
_assert(_isVisible(_file("profile-fileupload")));
_assertEqual("", _getValue(_file("profile-fileupload")));
_setFile2(_file("profile-fileupload"), "C:\\fakepath\\IMG_69546123046766.jpeg");
```

Comment: Please include more context and details.

Comment: Actually the script is recorded in sahi OS and I re ran the script and the playback fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't record a file upload. Sahi just provided a dummy path for file upload. If you look at this:

```
_setFile2(_file("profile-fileupload"), "C:\\fakepath\\IMG_69546123046766.jpeg");
```

This is using fakepath. Enter the actual filesystem path of your file and it will be uploaded.

Comment: Script in playback runs successfully, but the image in path is not uploaded after I modified another file image path in script. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I used the native event for upload 
setFileUpload(_file("id"), "C:\\abc\\efg.jpg");
This worked well in sahi pro trial version, but I recorded the script in sahi OS , it gave error like:
ReferenceError: "_focusWindow" is not defined, and playback stopped.